# unicode error importing HTML code

Tags: python, unicode

I am trying to import the source code from a website, but the problem that is one of the characters trying to be imported is `î` and it is causing an error.

Here is my code:

```
import urllib.request
htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen("url...")
htmltext=htmlfile.read()
print(htmltext)
```

Here is the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/****/Documents/Scraping.py", line 3, in <module>
htmlfile = urllib.request.urlopen("http://*****")
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 223, in urlopen
return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 526, in open
response = self._open(req, data)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 544, in _open
'_open', req)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 504, in _call_chain
result = func(*args)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1346, in http_open
return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/urllib/request.py", line 1318, in do_open
encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1239, in request
self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1250, in _send_request
self.putrequest(method, url, **skips)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/http/client.py", line 1117, in putrequest
self._output(request.encode('ascii'))
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xee' in position 32: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Also this happens:

```
"http://...url...".encode('ascii')
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<pyshell#11>", line 1, in <module>
"http://www....url...".encode('ascii')
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\xee' in position 50: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace? Which line had the error?

Comment: updated in the post

Comment: That seems to be a problem sending the GET request. Is there something odd in the url itself? You could try manually encoding your url `"url...".encode('ascii')` to see if it blows up.

Comment: That's the problem. The non-ascii characters in your url need to be escaped, and thats something of a dark art (different parts of the url have different rules). I'm poking around for a good solution.

Comment: When you assemble the url... does it have a path? a query string? You could pass those components through `urllib.parse.quote`. but not everything should be quoted. For instance, the host name likely not. And you want to do the parts of the query string so that ? and = remain.

Comment: I'll just give you the url because obviously it is causing problems

Comment: http://www.lolking.net/summoner/euw/73297206/Captaîn%20Riven?scroll=382

Comment: Hmmm... that url is already encoded. I think stackoverflow did it for you. How about re-posting that with tick marks like when quoting code so we see the unicode chars.

Comment: sure will do thanks @tdelaney

Comment: Can you use UTF-8 instead of ASCII?

Answer (score -1):

Did you try to add decode to urlopen? add `(...).urlopen(URL).decode('utf-8')`

Comment: There is no need to do that in the example given. OP is just printing the bytes object. And it may not be needed in general - xml parsers should figure out encoding themselves.

Comment: yes still the same error occurs

Comment: But if im thinking right you need to decode the string itself. So maybe im the urlopen().Decode('utf-8') or read().Decode('utf-8')

Comment: It depends on what you plan to do with it. The read gives a `bytes` object. If you plan to pass it to an html parser, they usually prefer that you pass in the `bytes`. They'll peek at the front of the document to get the encoding information. Some docs may be in error and not have that stufff... that's when you have to decode it yourself.

Comment: doing "url".encode('utf-8') works if that helps

Comment: @MitchShephard - that can work with some characters to some web sites. Its also common to use `urllib.parse.quote`.

Comment: Great. Nowadays you can specify utf-8 urls not only the normal ascii coded. For example you can specify ``www.example.com/óąś-slug,123/`` instead ``www.example.com/oas-slug,123/``